# Still facing squid:S2095 in Sonar / How to upgrade SonarJava in Sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-plugin

I freshly installed the newest version of Sonarqube and ran the inspection. I got warnings regarding squid:S2095 (closing of streams) which are false positives and which should be fixed with version 3.14 of SonarJava (see https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1478).

Comment: Which version, exactly, did you install?

Comment: I donwloaded sonarqube-5.6.6.zip from https://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/

Answer (score 1):

The LTS version of SonarQube comes with the versions of the analyzers that were current when the base version was released.

In your case, that means that your download of 5.6.6 included SonarJava 3.13.1, which was the current version when 5.6 was released. Analyzer versions are not bumped up with point releases because point releases only *fix bugs* and an analyzer upgrade would be a feature.

Because analyzers release so much more frequently than the platform, as a general policy you should always check your SonarQube update center for newer versions after you download a SonarQube version.

Answer (score 0):

As I had a freshly installed Sonarqube I was expecting I'd have the latest SonarJava plugin installed which is not the case.
Log into your sonarqube interface (admin/admin is default for freshly installed service) and go to http://host-of-sonarqube/updatecenter/installed and update your SonarJAva plugin.